# Adding Text After Specific Line of File in Bash Script w/o SED

Tags: bash, sed, lines

I am trying to append a line under a specific line, lets say [BELOW HERE] and without using SED. What is the best alternative way to do this?

I've tried to use SED but this was not supported for the machine where the script was made for.

```
sed --in-place "/^\[BELOW HERE\]/a BLabla=Database toolSomething" file
```

/a = append

Comment: Show us your effort please.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: StackOverflow is not a _write-code-for-me_ resource.

Comment: I did not ask for someone to write me code, I was trying to search for an alternative way which PS gave me. I do get your point though.

Comment: I've edited the first post with my efforts, thanks for the advice. It's my first day on Stackoverflow and just started coding. Sorry for that.

Comment: Since you are new here, do remember to go through the help centre topics on what to do when someone answers your question. General rule is to click on a small tick on the left of the answer( to mark the post resolved), which helped you solve the problem (or) the one most likely to guide you through in solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `awk`, `sed` or any other third party built-ins for this trivial task. You can use the `ed` editor available from the `UNIX` days available in all major distributions these days,

```
 printf '%s\n' 'g/[BELOW HERE]/s/\r/BLabla=Database toolSomething
/g' w q | ed -s file
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks.

Comment: He could've used sed too but just without the invalid arguments he was adding.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and its `gsub` function.

```
awk '/BELOW HERE/{gsub(/$/,"&\nTHIS IS NEW LINE ADDED HERE")}1' input
I am trying to append a line under a specific line,
lets say [BELOW HERE] and without using SED.
THIS IS NEW LINE ADDED HERE
What is the best alternative way to do this?
```

Not sure you do not wish to use `sed` : Here is one `sed` solution:

```
sh-4.1$ sed '/BELOW HERE/a\
"THIS IS NEW LINE ADDED HERE"' input
I am trying to append a line under a specific line,
lets say [BELOW HERE] and without using SED.
"THIS IS NEW LINE ADDED HERE"
What is the best alternative way to do this?
sh-4.1$
```

Input file:

```
 cat input
I am trying to append a line under a specific line,
lets say [BELOW HERE] and without using SED.
What is the best alternative way to do this?
```

Comment: awk '/BELOW HERE/{gsub(/$/,"&\nTHIS IS NEW LINE ADDED HERE")}1' input 
Works for me, thanks! Reason I want to use an alternative way is because it is used on an AIX system where SED currently is unavailable.

Comment: I don't believe there is a system that has ed and awk but not sed. I think you were calling sed with invalid arguments and misunderstanding the resulting error message. The right way to do this in awk btw would be `awk '1; /BELOW HERE/{print "THIS IS NEW LINE ADDED HERE"}' input`. The way suggested in  the answer will fail cryptically given various values of the string you're adding, e.g. try adding an `&` in it: `"THIS IS & NEW LINE ADDED HERE"`.